# Relating different surface code diagrams

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, surface-code

How do I relate the surface code plaquette and vertex stabilisers of this depiction of the surface code  (where the qubits are the edges):

[image]

to this depiction (measurement qubits are the black dots, data qubits are the white dots):

[image]

I understand that in the second one, the measurement/ancilla qubits are now pictured, but, ignoring them, how can I see these two diagrams as equivalent? I can see that in both, a qubit has an $XX$ and $ZZ$ act on it - but I still feel unsure and like I can't translate fluently between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

[image: Superposed stars and plaquettes]

The stars are the XXXX stabilizers measured using your circuit (c), the plaquettes the ZZZZ stabilizers measured using circuit (b).